# Facebook Share &p[summary] Not Prefilling Summary on Share

Tags: php, facebook, share

I'm done with searching all places on the net, but I cannot find a solution to this. I have written the code for Facebook share to share a post on Facebook using the Facebook sharer code. The `&u` and `&t` parameters for it are working fine, but I am unable to change the description for the same. The `&p[summary]` doesn't seem to work. here's my code:

```
<a
    rel="nofollow"
    href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?s=100&amp;u=<?php echo curPageURL();?>&amp;&t=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $desc;?>"
    class="fb_share_button"
    onclick="return fbs_click()"
    target="_blank"
    style="text-decoration:none;"
>Share</a>
```

Comment: Can you break up your code so it's easier to read? And explain what you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: And what documentation, if any, are you following?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell Facebook's old sharer.php posting mechanism isn't supported anymore by Facebook. The old documentation link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ auto redirects to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/.

You can though use the Facebook debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with Sharer, but you might be able to do this with Share Dialog.  The only formats you may use for *Sharer* are...

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url}
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}
```

The top format is the only format indicated by the **[Official Facebook Share Button Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)**.  To test this out, click "Get Code" at the [Facebook Share Button Configurator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/#configurator), and look at the generated URL.

So, no, you may not indicate a summary.  However, if you use *Share Dialog*, you might be able to do this.  That's right! Facebook has two API's for sharing!  Why?  *Sharer* only allows sharing a URL, and it is secure without requiring an AppId or registering with Facebook.  *Share Dialog* requires an AppId and registering with Facebook, so, you're allowed to set something like `quote` there.  See other options: [Facebook Official Share Dialog Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/).

The developers have also publicly come forward and said that they will not support anything but `u={url}` in *Sharer*.  To quote the [blog post by Ibrahim Faour, Facebook Team, April 24, 2014](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/357750474364812/)...

> We have changed the behavior of the sharer plugin to be consistent with other plugins and features on our platform.
>
> The sharer will no longer accept custom parameters and facebook will pull the information that is being displayed in the preview the same way that it would appear on facebook as a post, from the url OG meta tags.